# Power Apps/Power automate: invalid number of arguments recieved

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to use my flow on a button to create pdfs. It runs fine.
However it seems like my pdf is being named by a concatenation of all my html. ie `website_br_br_stackoverflow` etc.

So I am trying to create a dynamic name for this so my pdf name/ but getting the error `invalid number of arguments received`.

Can anyone help with this?

**Button formula:**

[image]

**Power Automate/Flow:**

[image]

concat(variables('var_Filename'), '.html')

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what you are passing to the variable initialization, but my best guess is that you are passing a wrong parameter.

Most likely, var_Finename received the first parameter(HTML) instead of the second (name). Simply make sure you pass the correct parameter:

[image]